# Broadcasting live microphone audio from esp32 to another esp32

Tags: server, esp32

My main objective is to use one esp32 (microphone attached) and broadcast the live audio from microphone to multiple ep32s(speaker attached) over the internet. Can someone please suggest me how can I achieve this? I thought of using WebRTC, but to my knowledge esp32 are incapable of that.

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a server with NodeJS like a Raspberry PI.
This Raspberry would have a public IP on some network, hosting a socketIO server. The ESPS would connect to that socketIO server and push their data via this websocket. The message could contain if it's a master esp's message or a slave. The salves which need the audo signal would connect to this socketIO server and consume the master's data.

Web RTC would be an excellent solution, but in order for it to work, you would still need a signaling server. And ofc implement the webRTC in C.